# Entailments Relations

Tags: syntax, semantics, lexical-semantics, entailment

I have problem understanding the entailment logic on these examples and would like some help.

Here's my answers:

1. Sally works together with Polly. 
   Sally works.
   => I think one entails other, but not the other way around.
2. In tennis matches, Bill regularly beats Sue, and Sue regularly beats Jack.
   In tennis matches, Bill regularly beats Jack.
   => Again, one entails other, but not the other way around.
3. Polly thinks that Fido is a dog. 
   Fido is a dog.
   Now, this is very confusing to me. I think there is no relationship between these two. They are not mutually entailing. They are not incompatible and one doesn't entail other.

Is my logic right?

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Philosophy or Formal Logic rather than Linguistics. Try asking it on [Philosophy.SE](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm not sure this cannot be a Linguistics SE question. But anyway -- your logic is alright. Except #2 -- you reason as if "beats" was a transitive relation (like "taller than"), but I think it is intransitive (think of "likes").

Comment: @bytebuster AFAIK, semantics is taught in practically every linguistics department, and these are the kinds of exercise they give. http://www.gist.ugent.be/file/216